# TensorFlow 1.6.0 doesn't show my GPU in Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've a problem to running tensorflow on my GPU in Windows 10. The code runs on CPU because doesn't detect any GPU. Anyone can help me?

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 9240676128181481018]
```

**Tensorflow version is 1.6.0, python 3.6.4**

I've installed `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` from pip with `pip install tensorflow` and `pip install tensorflow-gpu`

and also with pip3 `pip3 install tensorflow` and `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu`

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
1.6.0
```

**My GPU is a 1080TI with Driver 391.01**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 391.01                 Driver Version: 391.01                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   21C    P8    15W / 280W |    948MiB / 11264MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1208    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0      4616    C+G   ...6)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe N/A      |
|    0      8256    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0      8616    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0      8780    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
|    0      9800    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**CUDA Toolkit 9.1 with patch 1,2,3 installed**

**cuDNN v7.1.1 (Feb 28, 2018), for CUDA 9.1**

**Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.16299.248]**

---

### **UPDATE**

I've tried

**CUDA 9.0 with patch 1,2**

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:32_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

**cuDNN v7.1.1 (Feb 28, 2018), for CUDA 9.0**

but doesn't work too.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I found the issue.I  probably had a sort of conflict with the several packages that I've installed previously. I unistalled all tensorflow packages from my enviroment with `pip` and `pip3` and I installed **ONLY** `tensorflow-gpu` with `pip install tensorflow-gpu`.

Now working well:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 9774489396791002051, name: "/device:GPU:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 9234234737
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
 }
 incarnation: 10911103484745736471
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"]
```